# JQuery height() and width() return inches

Tags: jquery, html

I have an iframe that appears dynamically and i want to set the width and height of the frame to its child element so that there would be no scroll bars. However, in firefox the jQuery height() and width() methods return inch values instead of pixels.

```
var measure_element = "id_of_element_with_width_and_height";
width_val = iframe_obj.contents().find(measure_element).outerWidth();
height_val = iframe_obj.contents().find(measure_element).outerHeight();
alert(width_val + " "+height_val);
```

and it returns value of inches. This happens in the jQuery load event.

Comment: I highly doubt its returning the value in inches

Comment: I call bullshit, it's not april 1. ?

Comment: Last update of jQuery moving from px to imperial system ;)

Comment: @Arthur - you mean imperial system? You can actually set inches in CSS with `in`, and maybe jQuery would even return it?

Comment: LOL - Too many beers on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: What is the expected output and actual output?

Comment: Yeah, you right, imperial ^^ Morning beers ? (Montreal still am)

Comment: Nope, even setting inches, still returns pixels -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lxm9accL/, it even returns them correctly *(1 inch equals 96px)*

Answer (score 0):

All is alway in px with jQuery 
`e.currentTarget.offsetWidth === $('#el').outerWidth()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#el").click(function(e) {
    alert(
      "Offset : " + e.currentTarget.offsetWidth + " / " + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight + "\n" + 
      "Outer : " + $("#el").outerWidth()  + " / " + $("#el").outerHeight() 
    )
  })
})
```

```css
#el {
  width: 2in;
  height: 3em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="el">
</div>
```